# Mypy Config Class

Tags: python, config, mypy, typing

I am currently doing some work where I want to load a config from `yaml` into a class so that class attributes get specified. Depending on the work I am doing I have a different config class.

In the class I pre-specify the expected arguments as follows and then load data in from the file using `BaseConfig::load_config()`. This checks to see if the class has the corresponding attribute before using `setattr()` to assign the value.

```py
class AutoencoderConfig(BaseConfig):

    def __init__(self, config_path: Path) -> None:

        super().__init__(config_path)

        self.NTRAIN: Optional[int] = None
        self.NVALIDATION: Optional[int] = None

        # ... more below

        self.load_config()
```

When I am referring to attributes of the `AutoencoderConfig` in other scripts, I might say something like: `config.NTRAIN`. While this works just fine, `Mypy` does not like this and gives the following error:

```
path/to/file.py:linenumber: error: Unsupported operand types for / ("None" and "int")
```

The error arises because at the time of the check, the values from the `yaml` file have not been loaded yet, and the types are specified with `self.NTRAIN: Optional[int] = None`.

Is there anyway I can avoid this without having to place: `# type: ignore` at the end of every line that I refer to the `config` class?

Are there any best-practices for using a config class like this?

#### **EDIT:**

**Solution:**

The solution provided by @SUTerliakov below works perfectly fine. In the end I decided to adopt a `@dataclass` approach:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class BaseConfig:

    _config: Dict[str, Any] = field(default_factory=dict, repr=False)

    def load_config(self, config_path: Path) -> None:
        ...


@dataclass
class AutoencoderConfig(BaseConfig):

    NTRAIN: int = field(init=False)
    NVALIDATION: int = field(init=False)

    # ... more below
```

This allows me to specify each variable as a `field(init=False)` which seems to be a nice, explicit way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always `int` after `load_config` is called? (can it remain None?)

If it is always `int`, then do not mark them as `Optional` and don't assign `None`. Just declare them in class body without initialization:

```py
class AutoencoderConfig(BaseConfig):
    NTRAIN: int
    NVALIDATION: int
    def __init__(self, config_path: Path):
        super().__init__(config_path)
        # Whatever else
        self.load_config()
```

Otherwise you have to explicitly check for `None` before actions. `type: ignore` is a bad solution for this case as this will just silence real problem: `Optional` is used to say that variable can be `None` and you cannot divide `None` by integer, so it can cause runtime issues. In this case proper solution will be something like this:

```py
if self.NTRAIN is not None: 
    foo = self.NTRAIN / 2
else:
    raise ValueError('NTRAIN required!')
    # Or
    # foo = some_default_foo
    # If you can handle such case
```

If you know that after some point it can't be None, then the most clean is to `assert` it like this:

```py
assert self.NTRAIN is not None
foo = self.NTRAIN / 2
```

Both methods will make `mypy` happy, because `NTRAIN` is really not `None` in conditional branch or after `assert`.

EDIT: sorry, I probably misread your question. Does `load_config` need `hasattr(AutoencoderConfig, 'NTRAIN')` to be True to work? If so, the easiest solution will be

```py
class AutoencoderConfig(BaseConfig):
    NTRAIN: int = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
    NVALIDATION: int = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
    def __init__(self, config_path: Path):
        super().__init__(config_path)
        # Whatever else
        self.load_config()
```

You won't need any other type-ignores this way.

Comment: That's great, thank you. I arrived at the same conclusion a little while after I posted the original question -- I shall add my solution into the post. In the end I decided to use a dataclass approach where I can specify that the value is a `field(init=False)`.